# PHPMyAdmin maximum number of characters in table lines and field preview

Tags: phpmyadmin

I would like to increase the number of characters that are shown in table preview in phpmyadmin. I googled this but I could find a specific answer to my question because too many unrelevant results are shown in google. Does anyone know how to increase number of characters that are shown in phpmyadmin table lines field preview before the "..." is put?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is settable in config.inc.php, in the $cfg['LimitChars'] directive. If you have activated the phpMyAdmin configuration storage, it's also changeable per user in Settings > Main panel > Browse mode > Limit column characters.